# Calculate time span for given list of dates

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume I have the following list, where every entry stands for a certain time on consecutive days.

```
time = ["09:17:28", "17:47:45", "01:43:12", "23:18:22", "05:34:34"]
```

Let's say I'd like to compute the time spanning from the first event to the last one, or if we want to generalize a bit more from `time[i]` to  `time[j]`, how could I do this efficiently?

I tried the brute force method of splitting each element of `times` with `split(":")` and then trying to figure out a way where to add the necessary 24/48/... hours, but I just can't figure out a decent way to do that. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715493/calculate-time-from-list-of-dates) solution to a quite similar problem, but I'm having difficulty understanding what exactly is happening.

Any suggestions on how one should approach this problem?

---

In regards to the solution posted above: I do understand what the functions `to_time`, and `diff_time` do, but I don't know how one would generalize this if the date on which the two times are given is different.

What I have tried so far:

```
time = ["09:17:28", "17:47:45", '01:43:12', "23:18:22", "05:34:34"]
time_2 = []
for k in range(len(time)):
    time_2.append(time[k].split(":"))
    for j in range(len(time[k].split(":"))):
        time_2[k][j] = float(time_2[k][j])
time_2 = np.array(time_2)
```

This gives me a matrix where `time_2[:, 0]` are the different hours of the list elements... I fail to find an algorithm to that is able to catch which time represents which day.

Comment: Post what you have tried & how it came up short; explain what you *do* understand about the linked-to solution.

Comment: Work through a tutorial on the `datetime` package.  This allows you to work with times in most any reasonable format, do simple time arithmetic on them, and certainly cover what you're trying to do in this posting.  Then post your specific question.  "I'm having difficulty" is not specific enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ScottHunter I edited the question and tried to explain my problem.

Comment: @Prune Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try to see if I can do something with the `datetime` package.

Comment: @Goyo The only idea I have to calculate the time span is to „correct“ the hour-values. By this I mean adding 24/48/... hours where needed and then subtact the first and last time-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to check the total amount of time passed, assuming that your data is moving forward, you can use this:

```
import datetime

times = ["09:17:28", "17:47:45", "01:43:12", "23:18:22", "05:34:34"]
converted = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%H:%M:%S') for i in times]

a = [(k - j) if j < k else (k - j) + datetime.timedelta(1) for j, k in zip(converted, converted[1:])]

print(sum(a, datetime.timedelta()))
#1 day, 20:17:06
```

Comment: need to import `itertools`